# I want to display the uploaded image to the firestore in html img tag

Tags: html

I want to display the image which I have uploaded to the firebase firestore, and even I want to display the images according to the user id who have logged in and to display the image from their respective user-id folder. below is the code.

```
var storage    = firebase.storage();
var storageRef = storage.ref();
var spaceRef = storageRef.child('ProfilePictures/" + auth.getUid() + "/theUploadedImageName');

storageRef.child('ProfilePictures/"' + auth.getUid() + '"/theUploadedImageName').getDownloadURL().then(function(url) {


 var test = url;
 document.getElementById("profile-img-tag").src = test;

}).catch(function(error) {

});
```

theUploadedImageName must take the value or the URL of the image which is uploaded and display it in the HTML image tag!